# Flask Admin - How to fix or eliminate a datepicker truncated

Tags: flask

I have two datepickers for a date field. One truncated (flask_admin, I believe) and another is because the form_widget_args, as bellow:

```py
form_widget_args = {
    'date': {
        'type': 'date',
         'rows': 20
     }
}
```

How can I eliminate or fix the truncated one?

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

```
form_widget_args = {
    'date': {
        'type': 'date',
        'autocomplete': 'off',
        'data-role': '',
        'rows': 20
}
```

Comment: an explanation of how/why would be helpful

Comment: the statement 'data-role': '', eliminate the datepicker truncated.

Comment: 'type': 'date' provide a good datepicker.